# How to extract colon separated values from the same line?

Tags: python, regex

I am using python regular expressions. I want all colon separated values in a line.

e.g.

```
input = 'a:b c:d e:f'

expected_output = [('a','b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

But when I do

```
>>> re.findall('(.*)\s?:\s?(.*)','a:b c:d')
```

I get

```
[('a:b c', 'd')]
```

I have also tried

```
>>> re.findall('(.*)\s?:\s?(.*)[\s$]','a:b c:d')
[('a', 'b')]
```

Comment: Can you use split ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
inpt = 'a:b c:d e:f'
re.findall('(\S+):(\S+)',inpt)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use split instead of regex,  also avoid giving variable name like keywords
 :

```
inpt = 'a:b c:d e:f'
k= [tuple(i.split(':')) for i in inpt.split()]
print(k)

# [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way using `list comprehension` and `split` :

```
[tuple(ele.split(':')) for ele in input.split(' ')]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : input = 'a:b c:d e:f'
OUT : [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
list(map(lambda x: tuple(x.split(':')), input.split()))
```

where

`input.split()` is

```
>>> input.split()
['a:b', 'c:d', 'e:f']
```

`lambda x: tuple(x.split(':'))` is function to convert string to tuple `'a:b' => (a, b)`

`map` applies above function to all list elements and returns a map object (in Python 3) and this is converted to list using `list`

Result

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: tuple(x.split(':')), input.split()))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```